# How to enable build debugging in MSVS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I have a project in MSVS 2015 which keeps spuriously rebuilding every time, i.e. building always launches MSBuild which then gives a bunch of "All outputs are up-to-date." messages followed by "Build succeeded." instead of just doing nothing, as it should. In the previous versions of MSVS there was a (never documented AFAIK) way to enable verbose debug logging to quickly find the reason for this as explained e.g. [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewarnottms/archive/2012/06/07/enable-c-and-javascript-project-system-tracing.aspx). Unfortunately this doesn't seem to do anything with MSVS 2015.

Does anybody know what has replaced it or some other way of debugging this problem?

Comment: Have you set build output verbosity to Diagnostic (Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run)? Normally, the rather lengthy build protocol should give you a hint as to what is going wrong. Most likely, it's some file set to "copy always"... btw, if nothing's to be done, you might be getting output lines anyway, like "skipped xy, project not selected to build"

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I did try this, but it doesn't really help because the log starts with something like `------ Build started: Project: foobar, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------` and if there is some explanation of why did it start in 3000 lines following it, I can't find it. My real question is why does it start the build in the first place.

Comment: 3000? 300000 is more likely :D But if you know what you're looking for, you can drastically reduce this: look at the first lines for each of the projects. There, VS states a reason why it wants to build a project, e.g. "13>Project 'Rotor (Rotor\Rotor)' is not up to date. Last build was with unsaved files." or "17>Project 'ProductDatabaseImport' is not up to date. Input file 'something.dll' is modified after output file ''."

Comment: There are no occurrences of neither "not up to date" nor "last build" in the build logs in the particular example which motivated me to return to this question, unfortunately...

Comment: FWIW I finally found why was this particular project getting rebuilt all the time: it was a static library built from a generated C++ file and, somehow, the librarian didn't update the timestamp on the library (almost certainly because the generated file didn't change, and so the object file probably didn't change neither). So the output was older than dependencies. It took me an awfully long time to find it though, so I still wish there were a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem checking out and unzipping some files that had a future date on them.  This caused the entire project to rebuild even with no changes.

On *nix system, I would have used `touch` to fix, but on Windows I used the `FOR` command on cmd.exe:

```
FOR /R %I in (*.*) do copy /b "%I" +,,
```

Which updates the timestamp to current (iirc).

---

Before I figured it out, I tried to change the verbosity of the build process.  You need to restart VS2015 after changing this setting:

[image: Tools->options Projects&Settings->Build and Run; Build Output : Verbose]

---

Also, turn on the startup banner using `Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General`. This gives you some more build commands.

Comment: The trouble is that this (date in the future) is just one of many, or at least several, possible reasons for spurious rebuilds. I did see this one in the past and I also saw the most common one which is having a non-existent file (not used otherwise, e.g. a header) in the project. And I described a new one to me above. Build debugging in previous MSVS versions helped a lot with directly finding what was wrong, MSBuild verbose diagnostics don't really help with this (see my replies to comments above as to why). I'm really stumped as to why they would remove such a useful feature...